# Very Slow Performance on SUM SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table of likes/dislikes that contains around 5 million rows.  When I use the following query to get the data, it completes in 2+ minutes.  Is there a better approach to how I store and retrieve the likes/dislikes?  Every time someone likes/dislikes a post it adds a column to the db. 0 For dislike and 1 for like.  I then need the sum of both columns for each user and then return the users with the most amount of likes versus dislikes. If I take out the SUMs for likes/dislikes, the query returns in 4 seconds.  I also have indexes on UserID and everything that I am grouping by. Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 50
    Flows_Users.UserName, 
    Flows_Users.UserID,Flows_Users.ImageName, 
    Flows_Users.DisplayName,        
    Flows_UserBios.bio,
    FlowsCount = (SELECT Count(1) FROM Flows_Flows 
                  WHERE UserID = Flows_Users.UserID AND Flows_Flows.Active = '1'),
    BeatsCount = (SELECT Count(1) FROM Flows_Beats 
                  WHERE UserName_ID = Flows_Users.UserID AND Flows_Beats.Active = '1'),
    FollowersCount = (SELECT Count(1) FROM Flows_Follow 
                      WHERE FOLLOWING = Flows_Users.UserID),
    FollowingCount = (SELECT Count(1) FROM Flows_Follow 
                      WHERE FOLLOWER = Flows_Users.UserID),
    ISNULL(SUM(Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes.[Like]) , 0) AS Likes,
    ISNULL(SUM(Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes.Dislike), 0)  AS DisLikes
FROM 
    Flows_Users 
INNER JOIN 
    Flows_Flows ON Flows_Users.UserID = Flows_Flows.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    Flows_UserBios ON Flows_Users.UserID = Flows_UserBios.userid
INNER JOIN 
    Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes ON Flows_Flows.FlowID = Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes.FlowID
WHERE
    Flows_Users.UserID = Flows_Users.UserID
GROUP BY
    Flows_Users.UserID, 
    Flows_Users.UserName, 
    Flows_Users.ImagePath,     
    Flows_Users.ImageName, 
    Flows_Users.DisplayName,  
    Flows_UserBios.bio
ORDER BY
    [Likes] DESC, [Dislikes] ASC, FlowsCount DESC
```

Comment: You're going to need to seriously format a query that long.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I ran it and the problem is with the two like/dislike SUMs.  When I remove that part, the query is almost instant.

Comment: You should include an image of the slowest part of the execution plan

Comment: Looks like you have too many useless group by fields. You should isolate you group by statement in order to avoid this kind of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to join with 5-million rows table. If you take a look at the execution plan, I bet you will find that join between Flows and Likes_Dislikes is hashjoin - which is the worst possible case.

First step in optimizing this query is to detect which particular join adds time to execution. Supposedly, there is a part of this query which executes in acceptable time (e.g. 1-2 seconds). Everything else is the problem. And problems are solved by denormalizing tables. Instead of joining with likes/dislikes table, add likes/dislikes score column to Flow table. Whenever you insert to likes/dislikes, immediately update Flow record. By doing that, you will not need the heavy join in this query.

Keep in mind that normalization is a well defined theory, but that practice often goes against it. Striking the right balance between normalized tables and redundancy makes the great software.

Comment: I agree on denormalizing this with respect to counts like this.  And this could EASILY be handled with simple triggers.